# Windows 7 + Ubuntu Dual boot disk partition problems on a Lenovo help?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm trying to put Ubuntu on my new Lenovo y580 for school. According to the internet, I must partition my hard drive to give Ubuntu a home. When I break off 50GB of my C drive, I encounter two problems:

1) It automatically makes the partition a dynamic type instead of basic; you cannot install an OS on a dynamic (from my understanding). If there is no better way to convert it to basic, I can use a Third Party program to do that. However...

2) Even when I click "Yes" to go ahead and make a dynamic partition, my computer says `There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation.` My 500 GB HDD is far from full, and I tried shrinking the partition to 10GB, same error.

I am using the 12.04.1. Since I'm using a laptop, I do not have the option to just use another HDD. First time trying to dual boot.

Rapid fire: Is 50GB a decent partition amount? What is the difference between using the Ubuntu Windows Installer rather than installing it from a disk drive? It isn't like a "lite" version, is it?

CompSpecs:
i7 3610 QM,
8GB DDR3,
nVidia 560m 2GB,
500GB 7200rpm HDD

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic" partition?

Comment: @Histo dynamic partition is microsoft defined disk partition skim which doesn't have any partition table.

Answer (score 1):

I am sufferer & these are Facts:

1. Even if you able to install ubuntu in dynamic disk, grub isn't compatible with it. There is no way to install GRUB. Chainloading doesn't work too.
2. You can't convert to basic by any utility without deleting all partition and out data.

My advice

Take a backup of all data to externel disk or network computers.
Use diskmanagement in windows to delete all partition and convert it to basic.

50GB is very decent for ubuntu. I am using a 20 GB partition. All my movies, music stored in ntfs partition (can be accessed in both OS )

WUBI install will give you test of ubuntu but not speed of ubuntu. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

i also have lenovo y580. specs are little bit different. mine 750GB HDD. initially it was like this

1. 200MB primary partition (windows stuff, you cant see, it just there)
2. C Drive, primary partition (probably you had/have around 430GB, i had 670GB)
3. lenovo backup (a visible partition. primary partition, around 25 GB, there are apps and drivers are there)
4. OS backup (primary partition, around 25GB, you cant see)

used software: EASEUS partition manager 9.1.0

As you might know you can only have 4 primary/extented partition in a system, no more that that. look, i already have 4. as i have access to lenovo back up( apps and drivers) drive, i take a back up of that and deleted that partition.

then i need to re size my c drive. i resized it to 100GB(you can do whatever you want)

now i have

1. 200MB primary partition (windows stuff, you cant see, it just there)
2. C Drive, primary partition with 100GB
3. unallocated partition (lenovo backup,25GB+space from C drive,570GB)
4. OS backup (primary partition, around 25GB, you cant see)

i have only one primary/extended to make. but i need 2 drive for root and home(you can also use one drive for root and home both, dont get confused :) )

as i can create as much as logical drive in extended drive, i have to make one extended. so you make extended and inside you can create as much drive as you want.

from ubuntu installation you can choose these drives as your root and home.